# How to find the wrong dates after an 'out-of-range value' error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, format

I want to convert a column in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` to datetime, but when I do I get the following error:

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

I found in other posts that this means that some dates don't make sense, such as `10/35/2021`. I tried to find the wrong dates by slicing the varchars to get the dates with `SUBSTRING(date, 3, 2)` but it turns out some dates are in the form `m/d/yyyy`, so when I slice I get something like `1/`.

I have no idea how to find the wrong dates, and how to (even though there are wrong dates) convert everything to datetime.

Thanks!

Comment: So some data is in `MM/dd/yyyy` and other data `M/d/yyyy`? That really is a design you need to fix.

Comment: And what do you think is the correct interpretation for something like "1/2/2021"? Is it January 2 or February 1? You can only hope to find obvious problems like days > 31, but that does not mean your successful conversion of other values is correct.

Comment: To detect wrong dates you can use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it returns `NULL` when there is a problem on cast

Comment: @SMor it think it's probably January 2nd, because it's US based.

Answer (score 2):

If some of your data is in `MM/dd/YYYY` and some `M/d/yyyy` this really makes for a bit of a mess. I would likely do something like this:

```
--Add a new varchar column (yes varchar) to save a copy of your bad data
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourData ADD BadDate varchar(10);
GO
--Change the data you have to the ISO format yyyyMMdd and store the bad data in the BadDate column
UPDATE dbo.YourData
SET DateColumn = CONVERT(varchar(8),TRY_CONVERT(date,DateColumn,101),112),
    BadDate = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(date,DateColumn,101) IS NULL THEN DateColumn END
WHERE DateColumn IS NOT NULL;
GO
--Change data type of your data column
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourData ALTER COLUMN DateColumn date NULL;
GO

--You can view your bad data with:
SELECT BadData
FROM dbo.YourData
WHERE BadData IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Now I found that I have some dates in yyyy-ww-0, which makes it a lot messier...

Comment: Just one of the many reasons why storing dates in a string based data type is a very foolish idea, @AldanaBRZ . Your data appears to have no validity, so basically the entire column is worthless and the data meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to locate rows with values that are obviously bad dates - disregarding any ambiguities - just use `try_convert` and check for NULLs

eg

```
with dates as (
 select * from (values('01/02/2021'),('02/01/2021'),('33/02/2021'),('01/13/2021'))v(d)
)
select *
from dates
where Try_Convert(date, d) is null
```

Comment: That looks like a good approach, I'll try it. Thanks! 

Now I found that I have some dates in yyyy-ww-0, which makes it a lot worse...