# Update some values in a column based on a condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-update

I have a varchar column that stores dates, but the formatting is very messy. I have dates in formats `mm/dd/yyyy`, `m/d/yyyy` and `yyyy-ww-0`. I want to have everything in format `mm/dd/yyyy`, but I'm not sure how to change the values that are `m/d/yyyy` and make them `0m/0d/yyyy` (and update the column in the original dataset), and what to do with the dates `yyyy-ww-0`.

Comment: Why not store your dates using a `date` data type, you won't have any complications then.

Comment: You can the TRY_CONVERT function with culture,   `TRY_CONVERT(date,YOUR_COLUMN,101)`

Comment: @Stu when I try and do that I get an out-of-range value error, because of the poor formatting.

Comment: @DouraydTLILI but what does that do with the poorly formatted dates? Because I need them as well.

Comment: @AldanaBRZ you can't just change the column's dat type, you need to fix the data or copy it to a *new* column first, use `try_convert` as suggested above.

Comment: You need to do a one off very long and painful process whereby you find all the different variations, work out how to deal with each variation and convert that to a date (either with different string manipulations and format styles) and add your reconciled data back into a date column. Even then if you have allowed varchar you run the risk of complete nonsense values so you will have no idea what the intention might have been, or also things like 01/02/2021, you'll never know if the user meant 1st February or 2nd January. But there is no way around this, you'll just have to use a best guess.

Comment: *"I want to have everything in format mm/dd/yyyy"* Don't do this, this just hides the problem; your incorrect choice of data type `varchar`. Fix your design, and use a date and time data type. You were already told this in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70422654/2029983)

Comment: @Larnu I intend to have everything in datetime type, but in order to do that I have to  put everything in the same format, and that's what I don't know how to do. That's what I meant by having everything as mm/dd/yyyy, I want to after it convert it to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select format(cast([column name] as date),'mm/dd/yyyy') from [table name]
```